# Is it possible to design a Turing Machine without extra symbols for this language?

Tags: turing-machines, regular-languages, formal-grammars

Is it possible to design a Turing Machine for the language defined as L = {0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup> | n >= 0} with only the symbols in the set of {blank, 0, 1}?

Comment: Share your thoughts on the problem, where your efforts got you, and why that leaves you with this question in its first revision.

Comment: @greybeard I was expecting to have an answer almost identical to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/125813/63801). Haven't accepted it yet as I don't want to discourage potential answers with perhaps improved and/or different point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, listing out all the transitions would be tedious so I'll just give you the high level algorithm (the idea is to iteratively match the first 0 with the last 1, while deleting both of them). Starting from the first symbol on the tape do the following:

- If the current symbol is $\varepsilon$: accept
- If the current symbol is $1$: reject
- Delete the current symbol (by writing $\varepsilon$)
- Move right until you find the next $\varepsilon$ symbol
- Move left (the head is now on the last non-blank symbol, if any)
- If the current symbol is $\varepsilon$: reject
- If the current symbol is $0$: reject
- Delete the current symbol (by writing $\varepsilon$)
- Move left until you find the previous $\varepsilon$ symbol
- Move right (the head is now on the first non-blank symbol, if any)
- Repeat

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the idea is basically that you're going to turn the first 0 into blank, and then go search for the last 1 and turn it in into blank, then go back to the beginning and proceed recursively in the same fashion.

Here's [an implementation on the online turing machine simulator](http://turingmachinesimulator.com/shared/attqjanfyp)

Comment: That Turing machine does not seen to recognize $L$.  For example it does not recognize $\varepsilon \in L$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice! I edited my answer, it is enough to add the transition from the initial state to the accept state when the head is on blank.